# Receiving Unterminated CSV Quoted Field Error while inserting into Postgres using Copy

Tags: excel, postgresql, csv, copy

I am trying to insert CSV file into Postgres using Copy command at the time I am receiving Unterminated CSV Quoted Field error (out of 100 CSV files I am getting this error for 2-5 files).

I will usually identify the error file then I will open the same using Microsoft Excel and I will simply save without doing anything changes. Then I will try to copy the same file again into Postgres, this time it was working the data get inserted. Can anyone please explain how its possible simply opening and saving the file using Excel will resolve this error?

Comment: How shall we answer this question without seeing the data, the table definition and the `COPY` statement?

Comment: If you're looking for an Excel answer then you should add its tag to the question